# Violation of Primary Key Constraint when inserting into empty table

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I'm trying to copy select information from one database to another using SSIS. I scripted the new table directly from the old in SSMS so they should be identical. They are set up as [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5] with a clustered PK of [Col1] and [Col2].

I started with a data flow task set up in SSIS with an OLEDB source with the select statement

```
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5] FROM [DBO].[dbo].[table] WHERE [Col5] LIKE 'AB%'
```

then a SQL Server destination. I kept getting a Primary Key Constraint error so I changed it to an OLEDB source and a file destination for error handling. 615911 rows were written to the db and an additional 49970 to the file.

I can't find any common thread between the rejected rows. They are all unique, as they'd have to be since the PK Constraint on the source table is identical to that of the destination. I've spot checked and none exist in the destination table, though I still get PK errors when I try to copy from the error output file to the destination table. No entries with even the same [Col1] or [Col2] exist in the destination table as far as I can tell, though other rows do have duplicates [Col1] or [Col2].

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the PK on the destination table is on both columns and not only one of them?

Comment: Check again if the schemas of both tables area identical.

Comment: Modify your destination table. Remove the primary key. Run the package. All your data should load. Then run a query to find duplicates `SELECT D.Col1, D.Col2 FROM dbo.Table AS D GROUP BY D.Col1, D.Col2 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;` Does that query yield anything? If so, then you have your duplicates. If it does not, then your primary key is not what you have specified.

Comment: I checked double checked and triple checked that the schemas were identical. I know the PK on the destination table is on both columns because I checked and also because SSIS gives the first PK value that caused issues and gave both column values as the PK value.

Comment: to billinkc: I did get about 100 duplicated rows by doing that. But how? They aren't duplicated in the source, just in the destination. And why did it reject 49k rows with the PK set up but only gave me 100 duplicates when I removed the PK? Each row has a count of 2. Also, the row count of the table with the duplicates matches the individual records I was trying to bring over. How did that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source table is case sensitive. The destination table was not. Dropping it and creating it again while changing the collation for Col1 to CS instead of CI worked.

I still don't know why there were discrepancies between duplicates returned after removing the PK and rows kicked to the error file, but that's not important as long as it's working.